# NancyFX deserialized datetime to Local kind

Tags: c#, datetime, nancy

When NancyFx applies a `Bind<>()` on an object with `DateTime` property, it created a `Local` DateTime, instead of a `Utc` DateTime.

Here's the body received from client javascript (I deserialized it separately and this is the result):

```
{
    "UnavailabilityId": 8,
    "PublicHolidayId": 0,
    "ResourceId": 2,
    "Reason": "Lunch bitches",
    "StartDate": "2015-03-09T23:00:00.000Z", // <-- HERE. It's 'Zulu' time
    "EndDate": "2015-03-09T23:00:00.000Z",  // <-- HERE. It's 'Zulu' time
    "StartTime": "690",
    "EndTime": "810",
    "ContactTypeId": 13
}
```

object after deserialization with `this.Bind<ModifyUnavailabilityCommand>()` :
[image: deserialized object from NancyFx]

Why is NancyFx seeing this as a `Local` DateTime and not `Utc`?

Comment: How do you deserialized it exactly? Have you ever to use `ToUniversalTime` method after your process?

Comment: standard deserializer from NancyFx, and no, I haven't used that

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: How do I get NancyFx to deserialize a datetime to Utc

Answer (score 0):

You may use custom converter to extend Nancy Serialization process.
[Official example.](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Extending-Serialization-with-Converters)